# Using multiple rows in a mapply call

Tags: r, mapply

This seems like a straightforward problem, but I'm having trouble finding a solution here on Stack Overflow.  I have a data frame `df` with columns of data `a` and `b`.  I have a complex function (simplified example below) that I want to apply to all rows using `mapply`.  The problem I'm having is that I want to take an average of the `n` and `n-1` rows of `b` as an input into the function, in place of `b`.  Here is an example

```
new.fun  <- function( a, b ) { a * b } 
a        <- seq( from = 1, to = 10, by = 1 )
df       <- data.frame( a , b = a * 10 ) 
mapply( new.fun, df$a, df$b )
```

Short of making a new column with the average of `n` and `n-1` (something that I only know how to do with a `for` loop) and using that as an input, or creating a `for` loop, is there a way to do this in a more "R-like" manner?

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to add in the expected answer for the above example.  The averages of `b[1:2]`, `b[2:3]`, etc. should be:

```
 b2   <- c( 0, seq( from = 15, to = 95, by = 10 ) )
```

EDIT2: Had the wrong number of terms in here....set first term to 0 for these purposes

And the solution to the whole question should be:

```
> new.fun( df$a, b2 )
 [1]   0  30  75 140 225 330 455 600 765 950
```

Sorry for the confusing series of posts here.  Apparently I'm not describing the problem precisely.  I want one variable within my `mapply` call to consist not of the value in a particular row of the column within `df`, but of an average of the `nth` row and the `n-1` row, basically a moving average of the row and preceding row, but I'm wondering if it can be packaged within the `mapply` call in some clever way?

Comment: To clarify, do you want to do that for every row (i.e. take averages from rows 1 to n, then 2 to n+1, then 3 to n+2)?

Comment: How do you want to handle `b[1]`?

Comment: `lapply(seq(n, nrow(df)), function (i) {
  mean_a <- mean(df$a[(i-n+1):i])
  mean_b <- mean(df$b[(i-n+1):(i-1)])
  new.fun(mean_a, mean_b)
})`

Comment: Yes that is right.  So the calculation for the 3rd row would use the average of `df$b[2:3]` instead of `df$b`.  And the calculation for the `nth` row would include `df$b[n-1:n]` instead of `df$b`.  Does that help?

Comment: ah, you want the last two rows in each case.

Comment: Why 5 for first term?

Comment: Shoot, should be 5.5.  Sorry about that, will change

Comment: Why it is the average of 1 and 10? Is it because `mean(df$a)` ?

Comment: Sorry about that, copied in the wrong code...Now it is correct.  I added in the `0` as the first term in `b2` for simplicity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zoo::rollapply` is a very heavyweight (and slow) solution to a lightweight problem.

```
with(df, {
    bmean <- c(NA, (b[-1] + b[-length(b)])/2)  # replace NA with desired initial value
    mapply(new.fun, a, bmean)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply(seq(2, nrow(df)), function (i) {
  mean_a <- mean(df$a[(i-1):i])
  mean_b <- mean(df$b[(i-1):i])
  new.fun(mean_a, mean_b)
})
```

You could use `sapply` if you know the length of output your function is going to produce.

See also `zoo::rollapply`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rollmean` from `zoo` package to calculate the rolling mean for `b` column and then multiply it with `a` column. (Similar to what @Sotos mentioned in comments.)

```
library(zoo)
df$a * c(0, rollmean(df$b, 2))

#[1]  0 30  75 140 225 330 455 600 765 950
```

Or by using the `mapply` function

```
mapply(new.fun, df$a, c(0, rollmean(df$b, 2))
```